# UIBezierPath - Add rounded corner

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath, rounded-corners, cashapelayer

I am using a `UIBezierPath` to draw a curved line. The curve works however, I am unable to curve the edges of the line.

[image]

If you look at the top/bottom end of the curve, you can see that the edges are flattened out, thats not what I want. Is there a way to curve the edges?

I am using a simple `UIBezierPath` to draw an (almost) semi circle. This creates the curved line shape that I want:

```
CAShapeLayer *circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
circle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(0, 0) radius:70 startAngle:1.0472 endAngle:5.23599 clockwise:NO].CGPath;
circle.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
circle.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.2].CGColor;
circle.lineWidth = 18.0;
circle.cornerRadius = 10.0;
circle.position = CGPointMake(100, 100);
circle.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
[mainView.layer addSublayer:circle];
```

Despite setting the `cornerRadius` property, the corners are not curved. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Include the following.

```
circle.lineCap = kCALineJoinRound;
```

For Swift 3.0 and above

```
circle.lineCapStyle = .Round;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.0**

```
circle.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
```

and if you want your lines intersections to also be rounded set

```
circle.lineJoin = kCALineCapRound
```

as well.